# C# Filter Listbox From ComboBox Selection Using LinQ

Tags: c#, linq, xaml, combobox, listbox

I have a listbox called lstTickets and a combobox called cboFilter. I am trying to filter the items in my listbox based on the ticket.District that is in the combobox. So for example if I select from the combox,  is the only team in the listbox. Any help is appreciated.

```
 List<Ticket> = new List<Ticket>()
    {
        new Ticket { Name = "Arsenal", Badge = "images/arsenal.jpg", Price = 900, Stadium = "emirates.jpg", District = "London" },
        new Ticket { Name = "Tottenham Hotspur", Badge = "images/tottenham.jpg", Price = 850, Stadium = "tottenham.jpg", District = "" },
        new Ticket { Name = "Manchester United", Badge = "images/.png", Price = 1000, Stadium = "oldtrafford.jpg", District = "" },
    };

 private void cboFilter_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
       var query = from Ticket in tickets where cboFilter.SelectedItem.ToString() == Ticket.District select Ticket;

        lstTickets.ItemsSource = null;
        lstTickets.Items.Clear();

        List<Ticket> tmp = new List<Ticket>();

        foreach (var tickets in query)
        {
            tmp.Add(tickets);

        }
        lstTickets.ItemsSource = tmp;

    }



                        <Image Width="200" Height="150" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Source="{x:Bind Badge }" />
                        <TextBlock FontSize="22" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="{x:Bind Name}" Style="{StaticResource HeaderTextBlockStyle}"/>
                        <TextBlock FontSize="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left"> € <Run Text="{Binding Price}" /></TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

Edit: Populating combobox in mainpage.cs

```
private void myGrid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
    }
```

Comment: You have already written code for that. What's the issue you are facing?

Comment: The query is not working. I believe the error is the cboFilter.Selecteditem.ToString() == Ticket.District.   If i write Ticket.District == "manchester" it works but i dont want to hardcode it in like that

Comment: Can you share the code of populating the `cboFilter` ? Looks like `cboFilter.SelectedItem.ToString()` is not having correct value

Answer (score 0):

looks like the ToString() doen't work property for the selected item.

```
var searchTerm=  cboFilter.SelectedItem.ToString();
var query = from Ticket in tickets where Ticket.District == term  select Ticket;
```

make sure you put a break point at search term to see if its the correct valueto get

but i think i know your issue, the selected item will return the whole object so do the following

```
var selectedTicked=  cboFilter.SelectedItem as Ticket;
var searchTerm= selectedTicket.District 
    var query = from Ticket in tickets where Ticket.District == term  select Ticket;
```

Comment: this did not work, the listbox still appears empty when an item is selected in the combobox

Comment: I am sorry misunderstoond the question, thought you wanted to sort you mean filter :(

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya your are right  misunderstood the question

Comment: @user10760051 try the second solution that should work if the whole object is being returned on the selected item, which it should

Comment: The selectedTicket and SearchTerm have a null value when debugged. Also getting a 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' error when a combobox item is selected

Comment: @user10760051 and what value does this have var searchTerm=  cboFilter.SelectedItem.ToString();

Answer (score 0):

Try checking that first you have an actual value in the cboFilter.SelectedItem and then if you do comparing the values using lower case. I prefer to use System.Linq, so I've altered your query to use that:

```
private void cboFilter_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{

   var comboBoxItem = cboFilter.SelectedItem as ComboBoxItem;

   if(comboBoxItem == null) return; // or log an error here or something if it should not be empty.

   var query = tickets.Where(t => t.District.ToLower() == comboBoxItem.Content.ToString().ToLower());

    lstTickets.ItemsSource = null;
    lstTickets.Items.Clear();

    List<Ticket> tmp = new List<Ticket>();

    foreach (var tickets in query)
    {
        tmp.Add(tickets);

    }
    lstTickets.ItemsSource = tmp;

}
```

Comment: The if() statement returns false and the query returns null.

Comment: @user10760051 - so when you debug what is the value of cboFilter.SelectedItem.ToString()? If you're not sure how to debug I'm happy to talk you through it.

Comment: The value shown is {Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ComboBoxItem} when i selected London from the combobox

Comment: if the SelectedItem is ComboBoxItem, have you tried casting to Ticket and acceding the District property?

Comment: @user10760051 - updated. I wasn't aware you were using Xaml. You need the Content property and you need to convert it to a comboBoxItem first.

Comment: No, how would i do this?

Comment: @user10760051 - I've added var comboBoxItem at the top and then use that all the way through. If it's null I simply return. If it's not null I get the 'Content' property and convert that to string to get the value of the selected item.